# Placing jar so that it doesn't need to be specified in classpath when downloading my source code?

Tags: java, github, intellij-idea, jar, classpath

So for my java project I use the classes of a jar-file I downloaded, for that I placed the jar in a lib folder. It basically looks like that:

```
  -lib
      -*.jar
  -src
      -packages
  -bin
      -compiled_packages
```

The problem I have with that is that when I want to run the compiled code from the bin folder, I need to specify the jar's classpath:

```
java -cp .\..\lib\*;. packageA.MainClass
```

Even when putting the jar in the bin folder, I need to address it in cp to work. I want to put my code on GitHub in order for my class to easily download my source code, but I worry that an extra classpath will cause to much confusion.

1. Is there a way to place the jar in a way that it is found automatically, or maybe a way for Intellij to find the jar without manual project structure settings?
2. If not, is it allowed to include an open source project folder into your own src-folder or does that count as passing it off as your own work? (I could in theory do that)
3. How do you handle your projects (source code) that needs to passed on to other machines and depend on external jars?

Comment: i would suggest using either gradle or maven to manage your build/project. they allow you to specify dependencies/build artifacts with those dependecies. Intellij also has support to enable importing projects using said build systems as well.

Comment: You could provide a shell script to invoke your program, which is what a lot of other projects do.

Comment: The question contains multiple questions.